# Pass object to jrxml, and object to its subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to a pass an object and a list to a jrxml file. I am sending object in parameter map and list in JRBeanCollectionDataSource. I need the object to be send to a sub-report.
1. what should be the class I should use for the object(as it is not a primitive data type but is a user defined one). Currently I have used java.lang.Object.
2. In most of the examples I have seen, either List or Map are send to sub-report. I need to pass Object.

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameterMap.put("json", taxYearReportBean.getTaxYearBean());
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, parameterMap, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(taxYearReportBean.getSmallIssList()));
jp.add(jasperPrint);
```

Class:

```
public class TaxYearBean{
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
String method;
List<LimitationBean> limitationList = new ArrayList<LimitationBean>();

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
public String getMethod() {
    return method;
}
public void setMethod(String method) {
    this.method = method;
}
public List<LimitationBean> getLimitationList() {
    return limitationList;
}
public void setLimitationList(List<LimitationBean> limitationList) {
    this.limitationList = limitationList;
}
}
```

Comment: In the subreport (that I guess is in the detail band) you like to only display 1 TaxYearBean? or do you like to display all the LimitationBean's, that are in the TaxYearBean?, can you post some relevant jrxml that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your master report must have a field of type List or collection.
this field must be filled at run time
your sub-report must have Data source :Expression JRBeanCollectionDataSource(your field name), Connection type : Use a datasource expression, Subrepot Expression : your parameter .
Passe compiled sub-report report to this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the object data as a datasource to JRXML.
Additionally, if the List should also be sent as a datasource to JRXML.

First design the iReport to accept Object as datasource:
1) Add the project "src" in class-path in iReport.
2) Specify the object package.className in JRXML report datasource.
3) Map the TextFields with the Object parameters.

Now in source code, use "JRBeanCollectionDataSource" Class for sending the List of Object in "JasperFillManager.fillReport()", for Connection.

Hope this helps.